# Can't load break points for a feature reciever - what's wrong?

Tags: debugging

I've set a break point in my feature receiver, but symbols never load and break points never met, what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your symbols available?  You might need to copy the PDB file to the GAC.  Here are some articles on the subject:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markarend/debugging-web-parts-and-other-sharepoint-custom-code)

You also might want to try inserting a line of code that pops up a window asking if you want to debug it.  From http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2010/10/debugging-sharepoint-feature-receivers-the-easy-way.html:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi
did you copy the pdb files to the GAC-directory where your assembly lies?
To do this, use TotalCommander or CommandPrompt to navigate to

c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL[Name of your assemlby][Version]\

there should be the .dll.
Now copy the according .pdb from your debug build, reset IIS (or recycle AppPool), open a page of your site (to restart w3wp), attach to w3wp with visual studio (ctrl+Alt+P) and activate your feature again...should work now ;-)

ah, one minute too late....anyway ;)